# Accidently have one linux folder inside other one - what happend to my partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

**New Linux user here, thus please hold your laugh.**

Due to users suggestions I removed the previous post and re-wrote a new one correctly

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

I installed windows and two Linux distributions on my PC. I use Windows for specific apps, one Linux Ubuntu for other apps and other Ubuntu for internet. The "not booting or working properly linux" Linux few days ago prompted an error: "0 MB disk space left". This day it even no longer booted properly, saying there is no space for that at all so I am writing this post from the "still booting and working properly linux" Ubuntu.

*After more thorough analysis it turned out, that even thou every single OS is installed on a separate partition with enough disk space somehow - as I browsed the partitions - it turns out that one of the Linuxes has been installed inside the folder created for other Linux.

This is the directory that I have found while browsing the system partition of my working system:

```
/media/$user/(broken-linux partition-uuid)/home/(broken-linux $user)
```

The `/home` folder of the "not booting or working properly linux" is available within the disk space of "working linux".

I have no idea how did this happen, but I suspect that this is the "culprit".
Do I have to remove both linux distributions, delete partitions and re-install them again properly or there is some way to fix it without so much work? I was suggested running live USB of linux installation and run gparted from there as I could resize any partition from there, but the one that has no space - sda7 - doesn't enable me to increase the size:

Comment: According to lsblk you have booted whatever Linux OS is on sda6 and mounted sda7 to /media. You are making life harder for yourself by trying to run two versions of Ubuntu. Unless you have compelling reasons for two versions I’d recommend sticking with just one and do everything there. Which OS’s show up on your grub menu when you boot?

Comment: Windows, Linux 1, Linux 2. Is this information helpful?

Comment: Ok so just to confirm, all 3 used to work but now one Linux does not work. Can you post the output of def -h please. There are two reasons why you cannot increase the size of sda7. Firstly it looks like all the space on the disk is allocated but even if it isn’t sda7 is mounted. It has to be unmounted to do disk partition changes. You may be able to get it booting by navigating to the filesystem below /media going to the home directory for your user and moving any large files there off the partition.

Comment: I still have about 70GB of unallocated space. Tried unmounting the 0mb partition by: # umount /dev/sda7, then running GParted - still can not increase the size. Output of "def -h": def -h:
Command 'def' not found, did you mean...

Comment: It’s df -h. My error, ipad thought it knew better :)  Would be worth showing us a screen shot of GParted displaying all the partitions on sda

Comment: Added df -h output and GParted screenshot.

Comment: Note:  If you system reports as Ubuntu 18.04.4, your system is a potential security risk, as you're well behind on upgraded packages. A fully-upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 system will report itself as 18.04.5, and a system reporting as 18.04.4 implies you've not applied security upgrades since before 2020-August-14 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ and note the date is the ISO release data, installed system upgraded before that date).  If you're online, you should check your system's security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have not been able to resize sda7 is that it is tightly sandwiched between sda4 and sda5. What I would do to increase sda7 is the following:

1. Backup any data you cannot afford to lose
2. Using your Ubuntu install media boot into a live environment (Try Ubuntu not install Ubuntu)
3. Using GParted move sda6 to the end of the drive. That will move the unused space between sda5 and sda6
4. Boot into Windows and using disk manager move your programs partition to the end of the drive next to sda6 (remember Windows will not use the sda naming). That will move the unused space between sda 5 and sda7
5. Boot back into the Ubuntu live environment. Using GParted resize sda7

Good luck.

Comment: I am certain that askubuntu would benefit if there would be more users like you. I did everything according to your instructions and I am back to my "lost" OS. Big thank you PonJar. Question answered!

Comment: Thanks for your kind words. There are plenty of helpful people on here who know far more than me. Just try to ask clear concise questions and you will get the help you need